# Angular CLI integration Meteor Client Bundler (MCB) - Webpack configuration?

Tags: angular, meteor, angular-cli, angular-meteor

I am trying to integrate Angular CLI with MCB from this [blog](https://blog.meteor.com/leverage-the-power-of-meteor-with-any-client-side-framework-bfb909141008) and this [tutorial](https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/meteor-server-side). I've successfully configured the webpack configuration which is ejected from Angular CLI core and imported server model in client side, the problem is while executing the Angular CLI am getting the following error

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at createSourceFile (E:AngMCB\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:15457:109)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing in tsconfig.ts file:
"../api/**/*.ts"    ==>   "../../api/***/.ts"